# Bitcoin Core 0.13 -- SENDFROM rpc call

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, sending

I want to use `sendfrom` bitcoind rpc method to transfer funds from my account to some address. Right after calling it, I want to get all the data about this transaction using `gettransaction` or `listsinceblock`. Does bitcoind's wallet system process a new transaction *before* or *after* responding with a "txid" to `sendfrom`? Is it safe to call `sendfrom` and `gettransaction` right after that from my python code for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's save.
The current transaction submitting logic (`CommitTransaction`) do report the transaction ID after adding the tx to the local database and to the mempool.
On top, it holds the `cs_main` and the `cs_wallet` lock which makes sure not other thread can manipulate the relevant data-structured during the time of `AddToWallet` and `AcceptToMempool`.
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet.cpp#L2557

This means, when you call a `send*` RPC command, you will get response (the txid) *after* the transaction was submitted to the mempool and added to your local wallet database.

Immediately calling `gettransaction` is therefore save.